# NopCommerce add new table - invalid column name 'Product_Id1'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm figting with add a new table in `mycommerce` engine;

relation

```
[Product] 1..* [Awards]
```

code files:

```
public partial class Awards : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public string AwardDescription { get; set; }
    public Guid AwardGUID { get; set; }
    public int Product_Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class AwardsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Awards>
{
    public AwardsMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Awards");
        this.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        this.Property(p => p.AwardGUID).IsOptional();
        this.Property(p => p.AwardDescription).IsOptional();

        this.HasRequired(p => p.Product)
            .WithMany(pt => pt.ProductAwards)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("Awards"));
    }
}


public partial interface IAwardsService
{
    void DeleteAwards(Awards Awards);
    IList<Awards> GetAllAwardss();
    Awards GetAwardsById(int AwardsId);
    void InsertAwards(Awards Awards);
    void UpdateAwards(Awards Awards);
}
```

and also the `AwardsService.cs` class which implements the `IAwardsService` interface (in the same way like `ProductTagService.cs`)

`Product.cs` code snippet:

```
private ICollection<Awards> _awards;
public virtual ICollection<Awards> ProductAwards
{
    get { return _awards ?? (_awards = new List<Awards>()); }
    protected set { _awards = value; }
}
```

but every time I load product fromdatabase and try to load the ProductAwards proparte I get the error

```
Invalid column name 'Product_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Product_Id1'.
```

what's going on ?

### EDIT

I saw the `Customer, CustomerAddress, Address` tables and I've modified mine classes to be looking the same as that ones and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Please check  that mapped table is having exactly same column name as defined in your class.

Here it looks like conflict as its throwing Error Invalid column name '`Product_Id1`' and name of property in your class is `Product_Id`.

Comment: In my table I have the following columns: [Id],[AwardDescription],[AwardGUID],[Product_Id]. They're the same as in the Award.cs class

Comment: Then why the error is Invalid column name 'Product_Id1'.

Comment: that's the reason of my question. The Product_Id1 column or name doesn't exist in my database or project

Answer (score 1):

In AwardsMap:

Replace this:

```
this.HasRequired(p => p.Product)
            .WithMany(pt => pt.ProductAwards)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("Awards"));
```

with this:

```
this.HasRequired(p => p.Product)
            .WithMany(pt => pt.ProductAwards)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Product_Id);
```